# How to create a disaster recovery cluster for MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql

Recently I'm being tasked on setting up a disaster recovery cluster for an old MySQL 5.7 production cluster in my workplace.

So far I manage to setup a single DR node on another location and set it as slave, then I change master to the prod cluster.  In the end, DR node manage to sync with master prod cluster.

But upper management demanded that DR need to be cluster instead one single node, and I don't really know how to setup a disaster recovery cluster that sync to another prod cluster.

And upgrade MySQL version is not an option...

Can anyone help me or provide steps on how I can setup the DR cluster that can sync to the prod cluster?

Thank you.

Edit: below is the topology of my current prod DB:
[image]

Comment: This is not a programming question. It would be better asked on [dba.se]

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular, I can't find the website that you mentioned...Or is that a website? The [dbs.se]?

Comment: Are you using the InnoDB cluster or Galera cluster?

Comment: @xonos that was a mis-type. I've already corrected it. [DBA.se]

Comment: @ROHITKHURANA, innoDB...

Comment: MySQL cluster is usually equates to a 7.X version. @Xonos can you edit the question to describes what the current cluster is? I suspect your upper management has enough awareness to want the same looking topology in the DR site. Your DR requirements should be discussed with your management to state what they expect to be the MTTR, acceptable dataloss, risk acceptance of datacentre outage etc. Keen in mind with replication that a 'drop database' will replicate. How do you handle that disaster? Recommend [watching these](https://www.percona.com/resources/videos?tid=All&combine=xtrabackup).

Comment: @danblack, I had added the cluster status on my current DB prod and hope it is what you mean by describing the current cluster and yes, my upper management does want to the same 3-nodes cluster on DR site as well.